# Content not showing after applying a full width :before pseudo on an element below it

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have built an example of a problem I am having in CodePen where I have some text which I am trying to make easier to read against the background it is on; the background image is being set using `background-image` and hence you cannot apply an opacity directly to it (AFAIK), so I have tried putting a full width background color on top of it and setting the opacity to darken the background - however this has caused content that is on top of it to vanish.

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/GqGgmG *(disable the `.bg:before` to see the content)*

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="left">
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    background: #20334c url("some_image.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.bg:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.left {
  left: 50px;
}

ul.right {
  right: 50px;
}
```

Why is applying a pseudo `:before` element to the `.bg` class hiding content that is on top of it?

Comment: add `position: absolute` to your `:before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:before` element pushes the rest of the text downwards as it has been assigned `display: block`. You need to take your `:before` out of the flow by setting `position` to `absolute`. This will allow the text and the `:before` to be able to overlap.

```css
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    background: #20334c url("https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/how-to/remove-subject_1408x792.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.bg:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.left {
  left: 50px;
}

ul.right {
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="left">
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the explanation - makes sense now ha! :)

Answer (score 1):

change  it to after

```css
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    background: #20334c url("https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/how-to/remove-subject_1408x792.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.bg:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.left {
  left: 50px;
}

ul.right {
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="left">
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
      <li>something here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: It one day you'll make it responsive, using "after" wont effect the positioning